# How can I make my RadioButtonList show up stacked vertically?

Tags: asp.net, radiobuttonlist

I have a `RadioButtonList` on my .aspx page and I load it in the codebehind.

How can I have it show vertically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the RepeatDirection to Vertical.  You might also want to look at using RepeatLayout=Flow if you have problems getting it to render the way you want.  Often, I'll use RepeatLayout=Flow and assign a CssClass to handle styling.

Answer (score 5):

```
RepeatDirection=Vertical
```